# Can we mount single SAN block level storage are on two separate VMs having different OSs

Tags: virtual-machines, storage-area-network, file-sharing, hp-ux, block-level

We have one VM having **HP-UX**, on which a storage area is already mounted from SAN as **block level vxfs**.
We need to share the same storage area on another VM in **real-time read-only** mode but we can only use **Linux or Windows** for this one.

Can we do that? If yes, How?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are using a cluster-aware filesystem as GFS2 or OCFS2, a block device can be read-write mounted on a **single machine** (or, more exactly, by a single kernel image).

Mounting in read-write mode a non-cluster-aware filesystem (eg: EXT4, XFS, ZFS, etc) on two or more boxes will cause serious data corruption, at a point where the entire filesystem can be trashed. While using a read-only mount (ie: `mount -o ro,norecovery`) should be safer, it remain a very bad practice so I strongly suggest avoiding it.

The simplest thing you can do to share your HP-UX filesytem is to create a (properly protected) NFS export, and mount the *NFS share itself* on the remote Linux or Windows host. For simple file sharing, this is way better than any other approach you can work out. Even using a cluster-aware filesystem (with its gotcha) should be an action taken only after other options can not be applied.

**EDIT:** I read on your edited question that you are using VxFS. Depending on its version, it can be used as a clustered filesystem. However, setting up and managing a clustered filesystem requires specific knowledge which can not be improvvised. I strongly advise against using a clustered filesystem without really knowing what are you doing. I reiterate my previous suggestion: for real-time sharing of the required dirs/files, I would use an NFS export in read-only mode.

Comment: Hi, your answer gave me more knowledge and clarity and I have edited my question accordingly. Kindly suggest now.